# Button Hover Effect in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm quite new to CSS and web programming. What I'm trying to do is add a hovering effect for a button. I'm doing this by using 2 images.

There is a button called download and in hover code I add:

```
.button:hover{
    background-image:url(images/button2.png);

}
```

The problem is the button takes time to load ie: on hover there is a delay to show the button.
How can i solve this?

EDIT: I tried using preloading,but there is also a kind of delay

```
div#preloadedImages
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
        background-image: url(images/button2.png);

}
```

Comment: You could try pre-loading the image, make a div with that is hidden (display: none;) and give it that background. This forces the browser to download and cache the image before you :hover

Comment: @techno the file paths are different, is that intended?

Comment: @Andy yes somewhere i learned to put that,i tried correcting that.Not working

Answer (score 1):

You need to work in sprites. So only one image is loading and then it switches the background image position so you don't get that delay.

Check this out http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp will explain it much better than I can.

Comment: Checked the Link.How am i supposed to create a sprite gif image.Is there an easier way than this?

Comment: Animated GIF? Or if it's a static GIF then just put them below each other and do the same process.

Comment: You see i don't know how you will refer to these images, im new to CSS,is there an easier way to do this other than this

Answer (score 0):

If the image takes time to load and blinks, you need to use **sprites** to avoid the problem.

The principle of sprites is that you have only one image (original image and hovering image on the same) and you move the cursor to display hovering image.